# Can't format M.2 SSD as ext4

Tags: ssd, format, ext4, m.2

I'm not able to format my new M.2 as ext4 or xfs

I tried using the Kubuntu installer as well as GParted live CD with no luck

What could be the cause?

[image]

Drive info

[image]

Comment: Have you tried any other file systems?  Does ext4 or xfs have anything to do with it?

Comment: ntfs worked fine but not ext4 or xfs, can I install linux using a filesystem other than ext4 or xfs?

Comment: I was able to format as btrfs just now, I will try to use it

Comment: Run a disk check program (for example `badblocks`) against the drive. It may be damaged.